# Fortify includes generated-sources in analysis

Tags: java, fortify

Is there a way to exclude generated-sources out of **Fortify** scan? I tried sourcepath option mentioned in the guide but it never seem to work for me.

```
-Dfortify.sca.sourcepath="**/target/generated-sources/**/*.java" or
```

```
-Dfortify.sca.sourcepath="**/target/generated-sources/**"
```

Both the above options ended up with the below warning

```
[WARNING] Bad value provided for option -sourcepath.
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not add ** to sourcepath, specify the directories instead:

```
-Dfortify.sca.sourcepath="module1/target/generated-sources" -Dfortify.sca.sourcepath="module2/target/generated-sources"
```

If you are using sourceanalyzer you can add the -exclude parameter, with this you can use wildchars, like

```
-exclude module1/target/generated-sources/**/*.java
```